# Auto Mount SDcard as a network share

Tags: automount, sd-card, shared-folders

Hy there, im new in the linux world so i apologize in advance for my dumb question. Is there any easy way to auto mount my SD-card as a network share? I am using a NUC NUC8i5BEH2 as Plex server and there is no monitor connected to the unit.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did with a samba share in the past, so assuming you already have a samba server properly setup, if not [you can use this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide), proceed installing cifs-utils:

`sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`

And add your entry in /etc/fstab filling with your paramenters:

`//server-ip/share-dir /path-to/mount-point cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,uid=shareuser,gid=sharegroup 0 0`

Create the .smbcredentials file in your home directory:

`username=<your-user-share>
password=<your-pass>
domain=<domain-name>`

secure your ~/.smbcredentials file:

`chmod 0600 ~/.smbcredentials`

test with:

`sudo mount -a`

this should work at boot time as well

Comment: The samba is working, i have made a folder in /mnt/sdshare with the folowing settings(i want this to be public on my network)
`[testshare]
path = /mnt/sdshare
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
public = yes
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
force user = shareuser`

now i can access the folder from the pc, now i dont understand the folowing
`//server-ip/share-dir /path-to/mount-point cifs 
credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,uid=shareuser,gid=sharegroup 0 0`

where to specify to auto mount the sd-card to the shared folder?

Comment: Maybe an example could help, in your fstab you should add a line like this adapting the ip, dir name,...: `//192.168.0.51/storage   /media/myname/Public/ cifs username=YOURUSERNAME,password=YOURPASSWORD,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`  using directly your credentials instead of a file. Let me know if it's clearer and if works.

Comment: @Hunor is your SD card going to be inserted into the Plex server?